# how to utilize cudaMemcpy and cudaMalloc?

Tags: c++, debugging, cuda

I'learning CUDA programming. To figure out what is copy unit of cudaMemcpy() and transport unit of cudaMalloc(), I wrote the below code, which adds two vectors,vector1 and vector2, and stores result into vector3. However, after compilation and execution, the result in vector3 was not as expected. I'm not pretty sure what is the problem. But, presumably, the functions, cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy, might be used wrongly. Does anyone know where exactly the problem is?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

__global__ void vector_mul(int *const c_vector,const int *const a_vector,const int *const b_vector){
        const unsigned int idx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        const unsigned int idy=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
        const unsigned int thid=(idy*blockDim.x*gridDim.x)+idx;

        c_vector[thid]=a_vector[thid]+b_vector[thid];
}
int vec1[64];
int vec2[64];
int vec3[64];
int main(void){
       const dim3 thread_layout(4,4);
       const dim3 block_layout(2,2);
       for(int i=0;i<64;i++){
               vec1[i]=i;
               vec2[i]=64-i;
       }


       //declare gpu pointer
       int *gpu_vec1;
       int *gpu_vec2;
       int *gpu_vec3;

       //allocate gpu memory to gpu pointer
       cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec1,64);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec2,64);
       cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec3,64);

       //copy data from host to device
       cudaMemcpy(gpu_vec1,vec1,64,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemcpy(gpu_vec2,vec2,64,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


       vector_mul<<<block_layout,thread_layout>>>(gpu_vec3,gpu_vec1,gpu_vec2);

       cudaMemcpy(vec3,gpu_vec3,64,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
       for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
                cout << vec3[i] <<endl;
       cudaFree(gpu_vec1);
       cudaFree(gpu_vec2);
       cudaFree(gpu_vec3);
       return 0;
}                                                                                                                                                                              1,1           Top
```

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array that is intended to hold 64 `int` elements:

```
int vec1[64];
...
   for(int i=0;i<64;i++){
           vec1[i]=i;
```

These are not correct:

```
   cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec1,64);
   cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec2,64);
   cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_vec3,64);
   ...
   cudaMemcpy(gpu_vec1,vec1,64,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(gpu_vec2,vec2,64,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ...
   cudaMemcpy(vec3,gpu_vec3,64,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

All of the `size` parameters for those operatiosn are intended to be the size **in bytes**.  So instead of `64`, in each place it should be `sizeof(int)*64`.

There is a CUDA sample application called `vectorAdd` where you can see an example of this.